# Import function's arguments in OpenERP

Tags: python, import, odoo

I'm new to OpenERP and Python, I'm trying to understand the various functions in the py files. There is an import function used in all files generally devided into two parts : the first part seems to refer to Python librairies (called modules ?) like `from datetime import datetime` or `from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta` but the second part, I don't know what it refers to.

I would like to know what the following functions refer to :

```
import netsvc
import pooler
from osv import fields, osv
import decimal_precision as dp
from tools.translate import _
```

What is netsvc, pooler, osv, decimal_precision, tools_translate ? If they are openERP modules, where can I find the code behind them, else what are they ?

I would be grateful to anyone who would be able to explain to me all of them, and any other similar ones if he/she knows of any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have installed some version of OpenERP that includes compiled files instead of the raw Python source code.

I suggest you [reconfigure your development environment](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/01_getting_started.html) by checking the source out from launchpad and running the server from the source code. Personally, I like to run it under Eclipse with PyDev, because it has a nice debugger.

For the project configuration in Eclipse, I just checked out each branch from launchpad, and then imported each one as a project into my Eclipse workspace. The launch details are a bit different between 6.0 and 6.1. Here are my command line arguments for launching each version of the *server* project:

6.0:

> --addons-path ${workspace_loc:openerp-addons-6.0} --config ${workspace_loc:openerp-config/src/server.config} --xmlrpc-port=9069 --netrpc-port=9070 --xmlrpcs-port=9071

6.1 needs the web client to launch with the server:

> --addons-path ${workspace_loc:openerp-addons-trunk},${workspace_loc:openerp-web-trunk}/addons,${workspace_loc:openerp-migration} --config ${workspace_loc:openerp-config/src/server.config} --xmlrpc-port=9069 --netrpc-port=9070 --xmlrpcs-port=9071

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I found the files compiled withing a zip file, but they are all in pyo format, so I'm going to do what you have suggested so I can have access to the raw code.

Answer (score 3):

All of these are openerp *python modules*:

```
./server/6.1/openerp/netsvc.py
./server/6.1/openerp/pooler.py
./server/6.1/openerp/osv/osv.py
./server/6.1/openerp/tools
```

except for `decimal_precision` that is an `openerp module` and you can find it into the addons:

```
./addons/6.1/decimal_precision
```

All those import are `relative import` that is a bad coding attitude ([see the relative pep](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/)). Fortunately the openerp team is moving towards a better approach like `from openerp.addons import this`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm using openERP 6.0.4 and I'm unable to find any of these files at the server location, I checked manually and with Windows search and no results. I'm using windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits, any idea where I should look ? (actually, in the server folder I only have addons, doc and services as folders)

Answer (score 2):

Those are Python modules.  They are not part of the standard library but some third-party libraries you installed.  They may be part of OpenERP, or part of some other library used by OpenERP.  If you open the interactive interpreter, you can import the modules and then look at their `__file__` attribute to see where the file is.  For instance, for a random module called `guineapyg` that I have installed:

```
>>> import guineapyg
>>> guineapyg.__file__
'C:\\Documents and Settings\\BrenBarn\\My Documents\\Python\\guineapyg\\guineapyg.py'
```

You should read [the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) to familiarize yourself with importing modules and other basic Python stuff.

Comment: I'm reading the files directly in the folder, they are not installed as modules in Python, when I type import osv for instance, I get an import error : no module named osv. So thank you for your help but this is not going to work I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the code in the $server/openerp/

all are relative path to the $server/openerp/

where "$server" is a path for your OpenERP Server

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm using openERP 6.0.4 and I'm unable to find any of these files at the server location, I checked manually and with Windows search and no results. I'm using windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits, any idea where I should look ? (actually, in the server folder I only have addons, doc and services as folders)

Comment: in openerp 6.0 you can find it in server/bin/

Comment: thank you again, but it is really weird, I don't have a bin folder within the server folder, actually I searched all the computer for osv.py for instance and it didn't find any file and yet openERP is working perfectly without any errors.

Comment: do you have any zip file inside the openerp . like addons.zip or somthing check in that.

Comment: Thank you, I have finally found the files but they are all in pyo format so I'm going to import them from launchpad as someone else suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`pooler` is a python module which keeps track of all the objects of your all modules those you've installed and its maintaining it per database.

`netsvc` module is responsible for `socket` services( default 8070 port to connect openerp )

`decimal_precision` is module which takes care of floating point numbers where required like tax prices in invoice depends on your choice 2 decimal or 3 decimal etc... which also depends on the configuration you had provided, This module is responsible to keep the same configuration for all such objects ( to provide same decimal precision )

`_` is a `gettext.gettext` alias, to keep the information translated for all the languages you've installed for selected database.

Locations:

```
netsvc $Server_path/openerp/netsvc.py

pooler $Server_path/openerp/pooler.py
```

$server_path - is where you've installed your openerp server.

`decision_precision` you can found inside openerp addons it a standard openerp module.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your explanation but I'm using openERP 6.0.4 and I'm unable to find any of these files at the server location, I checked manually and with Windows search and no results. I'm using windows 7 64 bits, any idea where I should look ? (actually, in the server folder I only have addons, doc and services as folders)

Comment: If you're running on windows, there are chances like those modules may be bundled in one compressed file(s)

Answer (score 0):

They're [packages and modules](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html), found [somewhere within `sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path).